# Arduino vl53l0x sensor

Tags: arduino, sensors, arduino-c++

I'm trying to make a toilet sensorish trigger using vl53l0x sensor, I'm having trouble firing an action **while my hand** is in front of the sensor for 5 seconds or so, while I've tried different versions of blinkwithoutdelay sketches, and other methods found online, all of them, trigger the 5 seconds, after I pulled my hand off the sensor, which is not what I want. Thanks in advance, I posted my sketch to what I got so far. Thanks in advance!

```
// Library for TOF SENSOR
#include <Wire.h>
#include <VL53L0X.h>

VL53L0X sensor;

// Time calculation
unsigned long startTime;
unsigned long endTime;    // store end time here
unsigned long duration;   // duration stored
byte timerRunning;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Wire.begin();
  sensor.init();
  sensor.setTimeout(500);

  // Start continuous back-to-back mode (take readings as
  // fast as possible).  To use continuous timed mode
  // instead, provide a desired inter-measurement period in
  // ms (e.g. sensor.startContinuous(100)).
  sensor.startContinuous();

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

  delay(1000);
  int tofdata = sensor.readRangeContinuousMillimeters();
  int distance = tofdata / 10;        // convert mm to cm
  Serial.print( distance );            // print new converted data
  Serial.println( " cm" );


//  Code for presence detection

  if ( timerRunning == 0 && distance <= 20 ){
      startTime = millis() / 1000;
      Serial.println("time started, starting count");
      timerRunning = 1;  

  }
 
  if ( timerRunning == 1 && distance >= 20 ){
      endTime = millis() / 1000;
      timerRunning = 0;
      duration =  endTime - startTime;
      Serial.println ("Presence detected for seconds: ");
      Serial.print(duration);
  }

}
```

Comment: If you want it to fire while your hand is in front (less than 20cm) get rid of the timer stuff and do whatever `if (distance < 20) { Serial.println ("Presence detected."); }`

Comment: but how to fire it after 5 seconds has passed ?

Comment: So you want it to fire after the hand has been in front of the sensor for 5 seconds?

Comment: yes, for example i put my hand in front of it, keep my hand there for 5 seconds, after that do something, if there's under 5 seconds, do nothing or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If want it to fire after the hand has been in front of the sensor for 5 seconds try this:

```
void loop() {

  // Get distance
  delay(1000);
  int tofdata = sensor.readRangeContinuousMillimeters();
  int distance = tofdata / 10;        // convert mm to cm

  //  Code for presence detection

  if (distance <= 20 ) {
      // Object is close, check if timer is running
      if (!timerRunning) {
          // Timer not running. Start timer
          startTime = millis();
          Serial.println("time started, starting count");
          timerRunning = 1;
      }
      else {
          // Has 5 seconds passed?
          uint32_t elapsed_time = millis() - startTime ;
          if (elapsed_time >= 5000) {
              // YES. DO SOMETHING HERE
              // and reset
              timerRunning = 0;
          }
      }
  }
  else {
      // Object is not close.
      timerRunning = 0;      
}
```

Comment: Omg, you have no ideea how much i've been trying to make this work, i'd wish i could give you a real beer :), can i somehow add you as a friend ? or something to contact you in the future ? i've tried searching for help on arduino forums, but people are evil there.. thanks again !

Comment: When someone answers your question, you can upvote and accept it. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Sadly i cant upvote, says something about 15 reputation, probably because i've just registered

Comment: No problem. You earn reputation and "privileges" as you use the website